# gif tumbnails goes blank after upload and when used they are still blank

Tags: wordpress, gif

I do not know if it was like this from the beginning or not. After I upload my *.gif* files into my Wordpress library they shown as blank and even after using them in the webpage by any webpage builders(elementor, wpbakery, ...) it is still shown as blank images.

I appreciate your answers.

i looked for files permission its all set to 755 so I guess that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I will post it here so maybe other people like me may deal with problem in the future and figure out how to handle.
It's simple. I didn't disable adblocker on my website. So I just did it today and it is all good.